# Template instantiation decltype & declval with std::tuple_cat

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

The following code compiles with MSVC, GCC and Clang if I make a full, qualified call to `std::tuple_cat`. But it does not compile on any of these compilers if I make an unqualified call to `tuple_cat`... even though I am doing `using namespace std;`!

If I call the function unqualified, all three compilers find the correct function - but complain about an invalid instantiation of `std::tuple<void>`.

Why does this matter? Shouldn't this make no difference?

```cpp
#include <tuple>

auto Test() {
    using A = std::tuple<void>;
    using B = std::tuple<void>;

    using namespace std;
    using AB = decltype(
#ifdef QUALIFIED
        std::
#endif
        tuple_cat(std::declval<A>(), std::declval<B>())
    );

    AB* ptr = nullptr;
    return ptr;
}
```

See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/l3P_eD).

Comment: The real question is why it ***compiles*** when fully-qualified. Having a tuple containing a `void` is highly illogical, as Mr. Spock would say. Not to mention tuple_cat-ing a pair of void tuples. Change both A and B to a `std::tuple<int>`, and everything's fine.

Comment: It's true that there can't be any instance of std::tuple<void>, but in template meta-programming it's often used just for packing template parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instantiating `tuple<void>` is ill-formed, but just naming it is not. The difference here happens to boil down to one case requiring full instantiation and the other just needing to look at the template arguments.

When you make a fully qualified call to `std::tuple_cat`, name lookup just finds something named `tuple_cat` within the namespace `std`. That's going to be some function template that takes a bunch of `tuple`s and figures out how to concatenate their arguments. No part of figuring out the return type of this function template actually requires instantiation anywhere, surprisingly.

But when you make an *unqualified* call to `tuple_cat`, we have two different kinds of lookup:

1. Regular unqualified lookup - which ends up doing the exact same thing as above since you have `using namespace std;` - it'd find `std::tuple_cat` and would be able to eventually determine the "right" answer (for some definition of right that allows `tuple<void>` to begin with).
2. Argument dependent lookup. ADL requires us to look at all the associated namespaces and other functions that come from our arguments. These include "hidden friends" - `friend` functions that are defined within the body of a class. To know if there are any hidden friends, we need to fully instantiate these types - and it's at this point that we hit the error and everything blows up.

This ADL step has to happen - we won't know that `std::tuple_cat` is the only `tuple_cat` until we performed that step.

---

Example of what a hidden friend is:

```
template <typename T>
int foo(T) { return 42; }

template <typename T>
struct A {
    friend bool foo(A) { return true; } // this is a hidden friend
};

using R = decltype(foo(declval<A<int>>()));
```

In order to determine what `R` is, we need to instantiate `A<int>` to see if it has any hidden friends - it does, which is how we get `bool` for `R`. If we made a qualified call to `foo`, we'd get `int`.